# Installation of asciidoctor on osx 10.11.5 for newbie?

Tags: ruby, macos, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I tried to follow the installation process defined at: http://asciidoctor.org/docs/install-asciidoctor-macosx/#rvm-procedure-recommended but it failed with the error message

> Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
>   showing last 15 lines of
>   /Users/richardcoffre/.rvm/log/1466510618_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log

Because I am a newbie, but want to use `asciidoc` format,  I need an updated and detailed installation process to install `asciidoctor`.

Best regards
Richard

Comment: could you provide the complete fail log?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
2. `brew install ruby`
3. Open new terminal tab/window
4. `which gem`, it should print `/usr/local/bin/gem`
5. `gem install asciidoctor`

We should probably create a Homebrew package for Asciidoctor, it's unnecessary complicated now.

Comment: This recipe leads to `asciidoctor: WARNING: optional gem 'pygments.rb' is not installed. Functionality disabled.` Running `sudo gem install rb-pygments` does not solve the problem. Any other hints?

Answer (score -1):

*I am aware this does not exactly answer your question...*

An alternative to this installation approach is to use an Application like [AsciidoctorFX](http://asciidocfx.com/):

[image: AsciidoctorFX]

Or even simpler the [preview extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previ/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia):

[image: Extension for Chrome]

If you are a developer, there is a good integration with several build system (maven, gradle, rake, gulp, grunt...). In that case the package manager will download Asciidoctor and the dependencies for you.